# Change default language alfresco community 5.1.x to vietnamese

Tags: alfresco

My system: Windows 10, Mysql, Alfresco Community 5.1.x
- I go to http://alf-trans.ossportal.org and download 2 file jar for vietnamese (alfresco-vi.jar and share-vi.jar)
- Then I copy 2 file to C:/alfresco/tomcat/shared/lib
- Restart AlfrescoTomcat Service
But language not change..
After restarting the services of Alfresco. I checked the entire directory does not find any files with the extension is _vi.properties

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco does not support all language out-of-the-box, the official list of languages can be found [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/language-support.html). However, there are Alfresco Community efforts to support other languages, information on that can be found [here](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Community_Translations). If you look at [this link](http://alf-trans.ossportal.org/) you'll see that it does appear that there is a Community Vietnamese translation available.